# How can I debug my IDE(Intellij) not resolving a dependency when maven can with the same java version?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

This is a short code sample in my unit test

```
 if (retries >= maxRetries) {
    return InputStream.nullInputStream();
 }
```

I'm able to run the tests fine (w this code sample) using mvn test

However in Intellij, when I try to debug these tests(Run -> Debug), I get the error "cannot find symbol - method nullInputStream()"

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

nullInputStream looks like it was introduced in Java 11 but my Intellij IDE is set at 17(See screenshot)

My maven which recognizes this dependency is also set at Java version 17(See output below)

```
...@...-mac .... % mvn -v  
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven
Java version: 17.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.2.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

[image]

Comment: It's nothing to do with dependencies. I wonder if it could be that you're debugging *into JRE source* that's < Java 11. Can you check the source version? I'm assuming it compiles OK *and* will *run* OK

Comment: @g00se how do I check/set source version in Intellij? When I google searched, i only found project version which I have in that screenshot

Comment: I don't know - I don't use it. Does it *compile* and *run* (not in debug mode)?

Comment: @g00se I figured it out and posted an answer. I didn't know each module was also associated with its own Java version. I thought it was just the top level project

Answer (score 0):

Under project structure, the project was set at Java 17 but not all of the modules were set to that version

If you experience this, make sure all your modules are also set at the correct java version

Comment: Glad you sorted it out